# Unable to install PHPUnit_Invoker on Windows 7

Tags: php, phpunit, pear

I am trying to install PHPUnit_Invoker. I run the command `pear install phpunit/PHP_Invoker` on the command line. I am getting this message:

> No releases available for package "pear.phpunit.de/PHP_Invoker"

I have already installed PHPUnit and PEAR on a Windows machine. Is anybody also facing similar problem?

I tried again and I get this message in console:

> *phpunit/PHP_Invoker requires PHP extension "pcntl" No valid packages found install failed*

Comment: Now today i again tried and i get this message in console.'phpunit/PHP_Invoker requires PHP extension "pcntl"
No valid packages found
install failed'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PHP extension “PCNTL” (Process Control), required by PHP_Invoker, currently does not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows).

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php (Jan 31, 2013)

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer? According to Sebastian Bergman:

"PHP_Invoker is an optional dependency of PHPUnit. The feature of PHPUnit that depends on PHP_Invoker is not available when PHP_Invoker (or its dependency ext/pcntl) is not installed."
Source: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker/issues/6

And php.net still writes: "Currently, this module [Process Control (pcntl)] will not function on non-Unix platforms (Windows)."
Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
>pear config-set auto_discover 1
>pear clear-cache
>pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

I had the same issue but that seem to have installed with WAMP on Windows 7

Comment: **-1**. This is PHPUnit installation, not PHP_Invoke.

Answer (score 1):

'force' should do the job

```
pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
```